# When I put my Dodge Ram 96 in drive it won’t go

Tags: transmission

When I put my Dodge Ram in Drive it wont drive and when I put it in reverse it won’t reverse I haven’t tried anything yet what should I do I helped someone pull a motor home out of the mud and that’s when it started doing it? Did I mess up my transmission. Also when I started it just a little bit ago it drove for about 1 min n it stopped going

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check is the Transmission Fluid level, if this is low, you will loose all drive.

There should be a dipstick for checking the transmission fluid.  Check the owners manual to identify it's location.

Check for any signs of fluid leaking under the vehicle.